# 500 Internal Server Error - All Ajax calls, PHP

Tags: php, ajax, internal

**Issue**

I'm receiving the same error (500 Internal Server error) for all AJAX calls on a site I'm developing on my localhost (WAMP). I'm beginning to think that it might be the way my server is set up. Maybe I'm missing a PHP extension or something? Any help would be much appreciated.

**Testing**

I know the code works fine because i've navigated to the ajax action on my browser. Also the code actually saves data to the database so I know it's finding the correct script and running it ok.

**Code**

I've simplified the code to make testing easier.

**JS**

```
    $.ajax({type: 'GET',
        url: '/cms/performances/deleteperformance',
        data: 'id=' + id,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(result)
        {
            switch(result)
            {
                case 1:
                    //Refresh the page
                    location.reload();
                    break;
                case 0:
                    alert('error');
                    break;
                case 2:
                    alert('Incorrect call');
                    break;
                default:
                    alert('default');
                    break;
            }
        },
        error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError)
        {
            var httpCode = xhr.status;
            alert(httpCode + ': ' + thrownError);
        }
    });
```

**PHP**

```
public function deleteperformanceAction()
{
    $this->_helper->layout()->disableLayout();
    $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender(true);
    echo json_encode(1);
}
```

Comment: You're giving us very abstract information about your php code.
However this looks to be a server misconfiguration. Its not the javascript.

Comment: Apologies if I wasn't clear. The code I've provided is the code I am using currently and the code that is causing the issue. As you can see I've made the code as simple as possible (only 3 lines) and I'm still getting the issue. That's why I'm starting to think it may be a server setting that is causing it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've finally got to the bottom of this. In fact there was nothing wrong with the code. However, I did have a plugin that wasn't being found during bootstrapping. This was then being run through my error handler which was changing the header to a 500. Once I'd removed the unfound plugin everything was fine.

Stupid mistake to make I suppose!

Answer (score 16):

Add this code at the top of your PHP:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1); 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

That will show you what the problem is in your PHP code. If it's a syntax error (seems quite likely for a code 500), then you'll need to either enable these options in your `php.ini`, `httpd.conf` or `.htaccess` files. Alternatively, just take a look in your web server error log for the issue.

A 500 error is not a problem with your JS - it's server-side.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have error reporting switched on. There are no errors in the PHP script. As I said, it runs fine, I've tested it. I've also checked the return in Firebug. I get the correct json encoded response.

Comment: You are contradicting yourself here - if you can see that the response is coming back fine, then where do you see a 500 error?

Comment: Clear your browser cache and retry.

Comment: if you can actually see the response, are u manually dropping a 500 header? otherwise this is definately a server config issue. Does your script terminate?

Comment: Ok I'm obviously not being clear. If I call the PHP deleteperformanceAction by navigating to it via firefox I receive a json encoded 1 as the response. If I call the action via the ajax call I receive a 500 internal server error.

Comment: Just to add to this. Before I simplified the PHP code, it was deleting data from the database. This worked fine, even though the response was a 500 Internal Server Error. I simplified the code to narrow down what the issue was.

Comment: You're sure firebug is requesting the same URL that you're trying manually? Perhaps adding the `id=` params is causing the 500. Since you're using some kind of framework here, it seems likely that other code is being triggered by something that the ajaz call is doing differently and so causing the error.

Comment: Yes I thought the same thing at first but like I say it runs the action fine. I'm using Zend Framework. It's very strange, everything seems to work and yet I only ever receive back a 500 error. This is happening for every ajax call on the site which makes me think it's a server configuration issue. Are there some configurations I should check.

Comment: Check your web server error logs - if your code is causing a 500, the log should tell you why.